# importdata() function not working, despite. it working recently

Tags: google-sheets

This week my importdata function stopped working. It used to update every hour with no issues, then I put in a script allowing it to update daily instead. This was fine for about a week, and now this week it no longer works and returns an NA. I removed the script and that worked for a day, refreshing every hour. Now importfunction does not work at all. its as if it is slowly decaying on my workbook. the same function and link work on a brand new workbook. [image]

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: I cant due to proprietary information

Comment: I see. Can you tell me the exact error you get when it becomes NA? If I understand correctly, you don't have any active script running now, am I correct?

Comment: I removed all scripts to see if this would update on an hourly basis. The csv data is pulling from our tables in periscope.

Comment: Your url is not working now. Can you provide another one?